# innerHTML modification visible after an `alert` but not otherwise

Tags: php, javascript, html

All,

I have a fairly simple javascript script that changes some text in my html page.  The weird thing is that the data is only changed if I have an alert.  If I hide the alert as a comment, the data doesn't appear on the webpage.  To be specific, here are the relevant pieces of the JS code:

```
var index=0;
var xmlObject=null;

function calcIndex(){
  return index++;
}

function showNextName(){
  retrieveNextName();
  var someText = xmlObject.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById('nextName').innerHTML=someText;
}

function retrieveNextName(){
  var index=calcIndex();
  request = createRequest();
  if (request == null) {
    alert("Unable to create request");
    return;
  }
  var url= "Ajax_retrieveName.php?index=" + index;
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = createXml;
  request.send(null);
  alert("abc");
  //If the alert above is missing, the html is not modified...
}

function createXml() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      xmlObject = request.responseXML;
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing that?

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: Ajax requests are asynchronous. You cannot know when it is finished. It probably has to do with that (although we can't know for sure, you'd have to show the code)

Comment: what can very often happen is that javascript code will execute before the page load or some other "ready" state but an alert will force some time to elapse, often just enough to allow for something asynchronous to complete. This behavior is relatively expected if your `innerHTML` call is after your `alert`. You probably need to wrap everything in a `$(document).ready` or something equivalent.

Comment: (But I would need to see more code to be sure. BTW, it's really really good to actually put the code surrounding the line you're having a problem with in your question description, not isolated so we don't know what is going on immediately before/after)

Comment: Please include the whole code and context that does the content insertion and provide the code for createXml.   Your alert is changing the timing of your code so it is likely an issue with how you handle the asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: I added all the relevant JS code.

Comment: No you didn't. These are just function definitions. Where are you *calling* these functions?

Comment: I'm confused - all those are called within each others, except `showNextName`, which is called by an HTML button and an `onclick` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that XML object is not immediately available, because the request isn't finished yet, so the callback hasn't been called yet. (Alerting allows the request to finish in the time before you clock the alert box away.)

A better solution would be to have an updateElementHtml(newHtml) function and call that from *within* the callback.